# OpenSSL: Unloading current trusted certificates and loading new certificate file

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Let's say I have OpenSSL up and running, and I've previously passed in a file, which I'll call the bundle, that contains multiple certificates using SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations().

Then let's say the bundle gets updated, possibly with new certs as well as certs being removed. I want OpenSSL to essentially re-initialize to use the certs in the updated bundle and to stop using the old certs it had previously loaded. It's my understanding that SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() simply appends to the existing set of trusted certs.

Does anyone know how to have OpenSSL unload it's current set of trusted certs? I want to avoid restarting everything, and I also want to avoid creating new context instances if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you want to avoid creating the new context, but it seems like the most 'clean' and simple solution, because 'SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations' loads everything into the 'SSL_CTX' object, so it is NOT for the whole library. Creating new context and the reinitializing it with 'SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations' is the shortest path. If this is not an option then:

**1)** SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(SSL_CTX* ctx,....) only calls 'X509_STORE_load_locations(ctx->cert_store)' where 'ctx->cert_store' is of type 'X509_STORE*'

**2)** I would suggest looking at the source code of 'X509_STORE_free' function (crypto/x509/x509_lu.c) - it does exactly what you want: it iterates over all 'X509_LOOKUP*' objects in the 'SSL_CTX' and frees them. Also look at the corresponding 'X509_STORE_load_locations' (crypto/x509/x509_d2.c) mentioned above.

**Warning**: I have not tried to do this (or anything simmilar), I'm not sure if the SSL* object (used in handling connections) or some other OpenSSL object(s) is not referencing the data that you want to reinitialize. I would suggest to write some simple test program first :)